# Simple Pig Latin Translator

Tags: c#, homework, pig-latin

The goal of my assignment is simple:

> Write a program that converts a given text to "Pig Latin".  Pig Latin
>   consists of removing the first letter of each word in a sentence and
>   placing that letter at the end of the word.  This is followed by
>   appending the word with letters "ay".
>
> Example
>
> Input: THIS IS A TEST 
>   Output: HISTAY SIAY AAY ESTTAY

I want to know if there is any way to write this part of the code in a different/better way:

> ```
> foreach (string word in engword.Split())
> ```

**Here is my full code:**

```
string engword = textBox1.Text; //english word
            string pig1 = ""; //pig latin
            string pig2 = ""; //first letter
            string space = " ";
            string extra = ""; //extra letters
            int pos = 0; //position

           foreach (string word in engword.Split())
           {
               if (pos != 0)
               {
                   pig1 = pig1 + space;
               }

               else
               {
                   pos = 1;
               }

               pig2 = word.Substring(0,1);
               extra = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
               pig1 = pig1 + extra + pig2 + "ay";

            }

            MessageBox.Show(pig1.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `string.Empty` is generally preferred to the empty string literal, `""`. Also if `pos` only ever equals `1` or `0`, why not use a `bool`?

Answer (score 20):

This looks pretty decent for a beginner. Some suggestions:

- Making a variable `space` instead of using the literal directly is actually a kind of nice idea. You can improve the code by marking the local `const`.
- Why is pos an integer? it only has two values, and you are using it to test a condition. Use a bool instead.
- For that matter, why have pos in the first place? Pos tells you the same thing as `pig1.Length == 0`.
- Any time you write a comment, ask yourself *did I add this comment because the code was unclear?* and then *can I write the code so clearly that I don't need the comment?*  You say

  ```
  string pig2 = ""; // First letter
  ```

  Dude. If the name of the variable is `firstLetter` then *you don't need the comment*.
- pig2 is just one letter, so it can be a `char` instead of a `string`. You can say:

  ```
  char firstLetter;
  ...
  firstLetter = word[0];
  ```
- You're using `pig1` as an *accumulator*; you're accumulating the final result piece by piece. This is totally fine for small strings. If that string was really big then this is not an efficient technique; you should use `StringBuilder` instead if you want to make an accumulator for a large string.
- Finally, like I said, this is fine for a beginner, walk before you run, and so on. To give you a sense of how an expert would write this code, I'd write it like this:

  ```
  string pigLatin = string.Join(" ", 
    engword.Split()
           .Select(word => word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1) + word[0] + "ay"));
  ```

  Which is nicely compact.

Comment: Unless I'm wildly mistaken, there is no overload on `String.Split` which takes zero arguments, which may be what lead to the question in the first place?  Also, you can just say `word.SubString(1)`.  There's no need to specify the length.  Also, unless I'm wrong, this will fail if the sentence includes a single letter word.  There should be a check on the word length before assuming that `word.SubString(1)` is a valid index.  Other than that, great answer, you covered everything I was going to say.

Comment: +1 simply for mentioning the oft-overlooked value of self-documenting code and forgoing redundant comments.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, `Split()` with 0 arguments is basically equivalent to passing `new char[0]` to fill the `params char[]` parameter. Pointing it out in case you were asking. If you were not asking, then forget I said anything.

Comment: `string.Join` needs an array, doesn't it?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, as of .NET 4, string.Join is overloaded to support IEnumerable<string> specifically and IEnumerable<T> generically.

Comment: As @StevenDoggart has pointed out, it is best practise to verify that input you receive is as you expect before operating on it. Given Eric's example, after the call to `.Split()`, I would add `.Where( word => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( word ) )` so that strings made up of spaces, or having many spaces next to one another, do not cause your program to crash. I would probably also check that `textBox1.Text` was not null before starting, but it maybe that it can be guaranteed to be not-null.